# Select all with EF and lambda

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I wrote this awesome code that I am having trouble using now.

Currently **working** example:

```
complete item = ReliableExecution.RetryWithExpression<complete, complete>(u => u.FirstOrDefault(x => x.str_en == segment));
```

and this is a part of the RetryWithExpression code:

```
public static TValue RetryWithExpression<T, TValue>(Func<ObjectSet<T>, TValue> func, Int32 retryInfiniteLoopGuard = 0)
     where T : class
{
    RetryPolicy policy = RetryPolicyProvider.GetSqlAzureRetryPolicy();
    using (DDEntities dataModel = new DDEntities())
    {
        var entitySet = dataModel.CreateObjectSet<T>();

              ...

                var query = policy.ExecuteAction(() => (func(entitySet)));

              ...
```

**Now my question is how to change the above select query to do SELECT * ?**

I did try this but it tells me things about errors I don't understand:

```
complete item = ReliableExecution.RetryWithExpression<complete, complete>(u => u.Select(x => x.str_en != ""));
```

Comment: Can you post the error message what you get?

Comment: @nemesv 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<bool>' to 'DDModel.complete'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I think you've meant `Where` instead of `Select` so it should be `u => u.Where(x => x.str_en != "")` but based on the error message it also won't work... without the full code of `RetryWithExpression` it's hard to tell why it's not working.

Comment: @nemesv When I do Where, I get exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`IQueryable<complete> items = ReliableExecution.RetryWithExpression<complete, IQueryable<complete>>(u => u.Where(x => x.str_en != ""));` ?